Docker public registry API V2 authentication
I’m trying to use docker registry APIs
I want to collect some data from the docker public registry (registry-1.docker.io hope this is correct)
But I couldn’t find the way to authenticate these APIs. Here it says use basic auth to GET v2/ endpoint . I have a dockerhub account and I used it’s username & password for this API, but it says unauthorized.
Can some one please explain me how I can authenticate docker registry API V2?

Docker Hub uses token authentication. The GET to v2/ includes a Www-Authenticate as part of the 401 response. That header directs you to https://auth.docker.io/token with service=registry.docker.io. And there you should request a token for a given scope. With curl, that request would look like:
mt_o="application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"
mt_ol="application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"
mt_d="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
mt_dl="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
mt_d1="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json"

# get the auth token
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
             -u "${user}:${pass_or_pat}" \
        | jq -r '.token')

# use that to request a manifest
curl -H "Accept: ${mt_o}" -H "Accept: ${mt_ol}" \
     -H "Accept: ${mt_d}" -H "Accept: ${mt_dl}" -H "Accept: ${mt_d1}" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${sha:-$tag}" | jq .


Before you write your own registry client API, realize that several already exist. crane, skopeo, oras, and my own regclient all have Go implementations you can leverage to avoid reinventing the wheel.
